# pick only documents types from storage using activity result API

Tags: android, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I need to make the user able to pick only documents types (ex: pdf, docs, xls) from phone storage using the new [Activity Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), but the problem is that when I launch the contract like the following code

```
private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    ...
}

fun pickDocument() = getContent.launch("*/*")
```

user become able to select any file type including images, videos, ...

Comment: instead of '*/*' have you tried like 'application/pdf' ?

Comment: @SimpleCoder this will allow only pdf file, I need all documents types

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()
```

instead of

```
ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
```

and pass the required mime-types in:

```
pickDocumentsContract.launch(arrayOf("mime-type-1","mime-type 2"))
```

example:

```
pickDocumentsContract.launch(arrayOf(
"application/msword", //.doc (Microsoft Word file)
"application/pdf" //.pdf (Pdf file)
))
```

You can find more mime types here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: Please can you give example of mime-types ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check mime types from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mime-support/+/9817b71a54a2ee8b691c1dfa937c0f9b16b3473c/mime.types).

```
private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()
) { uri ->
    uri?.let { fileUri ->
        //todo you have fileUri here
    }
}


fun startLauncher(){
    launcher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf","image/*")) //todo you can add more mime-type here...
}
```